# Override render of TextBox for entire ASP.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.net project that uses many asp:TextBox controls. When a page is being viewed in print mode, we want to display the HTML rendered for the TextBoxes different. Perhaps as a string literal. Is there a way to override / hook into the way TextBox is rendered on all pages?

jquery is not recommended as javascript could be disabled.

I would like to see a couple different methods this could be handled.

Comment: Why not create a new class that extends TextBox and override with the new functionality? Then just use your custom control instead of asp's TextBox control?

Comment: ASP.net TextBox is used about 500 or more times in this website, it would not be ideal at all.

Comment: Ah, yea I wouldn't want to be the one to make that edit.

Answer (score 0):

Do it on client side. Via `@media print { }` style declaration with a different style declared for `input[type="text"]` elements.

Comment: But CSS may be disabled. ;)

Comment: @CharlieKilian lol, moreover network cable can be pulled.. you can't win them all.